# Dataclasses for dataframes in the class

Tags: python, pandas, python-dataclasses

I have a Result class in which I calculate many dataframes (around 30) and assign them to attributes of the class.

```
class Result:
    def __init__(self, df1)
      self.df1=df1
```

I want to write the dataframes to excel at specified positions. For this I have a function

```
append_df_to_excel(df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=0, startcol=0)
```

which takes as parameters a dataframe, sheet_name and startrow and startcolumn.

What I am doing for now is I have a dictionary in the function main and I iterate thourgh it to write dataframes at specified places in the excel:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
      result=Result(df)
      dic_to_excel = {5:result.df1}
      for start_col, df in dic_to_excel.items():
          append_df_to_excel(df, sheet_name="CORE", startrow=2, startcol=start_col)
```

I am wondering if it is a right place to use a dataclass instead of this dictionary `dic_to_excel` in which i give poition of a dataframe in excel. In the dataclass I thought I could have a dataframe, sheet_name , startrow and startcol as attributes. Can I use dataclasses for this?

Comment: Have you tried? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: I don't see where you are using dictionaries. Your question is very unclear and opinion based. Most python instances use an internal `__dict__` to store attributes anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Result:
    df: pd.DataFrame
    start_row: int
    start_col: int
    sheet_name: str

if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = [
        Result(df, sheet_name="CORE", start_row=2, start_col=5),
        # and so on
    ]
    for result in results:
        append_df_to_excel(result.df, sheet_name=result.sheet_name, startrow=result.start_row, startcol=result.start_col)
```